# How to build tree from path

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, path, tree

I need to convert some path to a tree object.
the path should represent the tree with the following requirements:

1. for **'.items.properties'** after the key, the type should be array of objects.
2. for **'.items'** after the key, the type should be an array.
3. for **'.properties'** after the key, the type should be an object.

for example for this path:
`'key1.items.properties.key2.items.properties.key3.items'`

key1 is the key and the type is array of object.

This is the final result that I expect to get from this path

```
'key1.items.properties.key2.items.properties.key3.items' // path

//expected
{
  key1: [
    {
      key2:[
        {
          key3:[]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Edit:
I know how to convert this path to this data structure with 'json-pointer':

```
{
  key1: {
      key2:{
        {
          key3:[]
        }
      }
    }
}
```

So if you have a way to convert my data structure to the expected it's could help.

Comment: is it a new data structure or do you have a given structure where you want to include the new structure? btw, what have you tried?

Comment: I added to my question the data structure that I have.
if you have a way to convert my data structure to the expected it's could help.

Answer (score 0):

You could take the parts and look ahead for a key with a following `'items'` string, the create a new property with an empty array.

For `'properties'` create a new object and push it to the temporary array.

```js
var string = 'key1.items.properties.key2.items.properties.key3.items',
    parts = string.split('.'),
    result = {},
    temp = result;    

for (let i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
    if (parts[i] === 'properties') {
        let object = {};
        temp.push(object);
        temp = object;
        continue;
    }
    if (parts[i + 1] === 'items') {
        let items = [];
        temp[parts[i]] = items;
        i++;
        temp = items;
        continue;
    }    
}

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```